# Are these two regular expressions equivalent?

Tags: regular-expressions

$u^*v(w \cup xu^*w)^*$ and $u^*v(w \cup x(u)^*w)^*$

Is that extra set of parentheses around the second $u$ needed?

Answer (score 1):

First, an alternative notation (what I usually use, and it is my personal preference) to join two regular expressions is to use '+' instead of $\cup$ which is used to denote a union of two sets. So your regular expression can be written as 
$$ u^*v(w + xu^*w)^* $$
or sometimes
$$ u^*v(w \mid xu^*w)^* $$
instead of
$$ u^*v(w \cup xu^*w)^* $$
That pair of parentheses around the second $u$ is redundant and so not needed since the Kleene star operator applies to only $u$ in $xu^*w$, i.e., $xu^*w$ and $x(u)^*w$ denote the same set.

Comment: Using "$\cup$" to represent union is hardly non-standard. Sipser uses it and his book is quite popular.

Comment: @RickDecker  It is something like we use "$1 \cup 1 = 2$ instead of "$1+1 =2$". That said, there is no restriction in notation usage. Once Sipser defines join of two regular expressions using $\cup$, it of course can be used throughout the book.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Formal_definition) does not mention about $\cup$ as an alternative notation for joining regular sets. Hopcroft & Ullman's book uses "+", Aho's "Dragon" book also uses "+". However, the question is not about the notation at all.

Comment: @RickDecker Also, a possible reason for not using "+", in particular by Sipser, maybe because he uses "+" itself as a member of alphabet. Just in case to avoid confusion.

Comment: @RickDecker I edited my post. Now I think better. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not requirement of an extra set of parentheses around the second u in this equation : u∗v(w∪x(u)∗w)∗

because () is useful for more than one operand or operation required in one parentheses.

Comment: How is your answer different from existing one?

Comment: You all right. But answer is simple in true or false. So after reading previous answer at last some can understand the answer is what. so i simply give the answer.